# Looking for a page designer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My site currently has some static pages. I'm looking for a rails wysiwyg webtool with which I can change those static pages (with images) dynamically. The number of pages is fixed and I don't have to be able to dynamically add new.

**Update**
The site already has a design template assigned which I don't need to change. I only need to be able to change the content of some of the pages.

Someone can suggest me something?

Thanks
Stijn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a server site tool that facilitates editing static HTML files but uses a web browser interface?

If so I think that only solves part of the problem.  You pages still have, presumably, some common "furniture" like a Banner pane, Left pane, Right pane, Footer.  If you want to change these you will have to edit every file.  What about if you have telephone number in the Banner - if that changed it would be better to just change that centrally.

These are problems that a Content Management System addresses, so if you are not familiar with that you may want to read up on CMS.

To compare CMS systems see: http://cmsmatrix.org/matrix/cms-matrix?func=search

You can enter "Rails" or maybe "Ruby" in the Language field of the Search form

Answer (score 1):

Try [Radiant CMS](http://radiantcms.org/)